# copy UITableViewCell to uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

When pressing the cell (didSelectRowAtIndexPath), I want the cell be be copied to a view. And then I will have the possibility to move the view around, detached from the UITableView.

Is it possible to copy in 1 line of code, without to

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{  
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tasksTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIView* copyOfTheCell = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.frame];
copyOfTheCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
UILabel* title = cell.textLabel;
[copyOfTheCell addSubview:title];
[self.view addSubview:copyOfTheCell];
}
```

Comment: That would be one way to do it, unless you're thinking of taking a screenshot and moving that around, which will also do the trick.

Comment: Agree with @Jmarsh you should snapshot it and use that, the problem with using the UITableViewCell is you don't know if the table will dequeue it in the background.

Comment: I do agree with the others but just out of curiosity: Did you try actually creating (alloc/init) a regluar UITableViewCell, using a different reuse-identifier, add that to your view and copy all the relevant content from the original cell?

Comment: Or, if you stick to the idea of copying all subviews to an empty UIView with the frame (especially the size) of the cell then you could recursively to the same with all subviews of cell.view (may well be cell.contentView - have a look), copy their frames, values, colours, etc. pp.